# Any suggestions for a program or small project to learn about concurrency in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm aiming to learn about concurrency in Java.  Currently my state of knowledge is poor.  I'm pretty sure I know what "volatile" means.  I sort of know what "synchronized" means.  Sometimes.  I've never written code that starts threads or manages them.  Outside of this issue, I feel confident and at home working in Java.

I'm looking for suggestions for a small project or program which will require understanding concurrency to work correctly and efficiently.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're really just starting then probably the producer-consumer problem is a good way to start:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem

Don't read too much because the Wikipedia article also contains a solution to the problem :-)

Comment: +1 . IMO this is one of the best ways to learn threading concepts.

Comment: Had a quick look and I can see immediately that I don't know how to do that right.  So it fits the bill and I shall give it a go - many thanks!

Answer (score 20):

Write a matrix-multiply algorithm. Parallelize it. Optimize it. See how it scales especially if you have a multi-core machine. That would be a fun project.

Answer (score 13):

try a sudoku resolver, with various strategies:

[image]

- 3 threads : 1 for rows, 1 for columns and 1 for sub-squares
- 9 threads : 3 for rows (1 thread each 3 rows), 3 for columns and 3 for sub-squares
- 27 threads: 9 for rows (1 thread each 1 row), etc

Comment: There is an additional burden of solving a puzzle, which would distract from understanding the principles of concurrent programming.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with @Julien on mtrix multiplication . In this problem the improvement caused by the usage of threads can be much more visible .
But as apposed @dfa, I disagree with Sudoku. it is not sensible enough
For example here is my result of writing Matrix-Mul in threads

```
 %        self                        
time    seconds   name    
32.38    10.72    Simple
21.29    7.05     Tiling
15.58    5.16     SimpleThread
9.63     3.19     ThreadTiling
```

This is the result of multiplication of a 1000*1000 matrix . You can easily see that how much threading can improve your program speed . ( Tiling is a technique used to enhance the cache hit )

After that, when you became familiar with syntax, you may dive into classical problems. they might be a little bit more challenging, but it can help you to become familiar with patterns in solving concurrency problems .
I suggest to take a look at [Little book on semaphores](http://greenteapress.com/semaphores/) . It so comprehensive and can help you to grasp ideas behind these problems .

Comment: The book is really very useful, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a Complete project but it contains some source codes as well. I think it would be great for get a good understanding about threading.

[Threading in Java](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-1996/jw-04-threads.html?page=1)

Answer (score 2):

If you are an somewhat experienced programmer it might be interesting to create a little server for prescribing to share prices that uses the [Fix Protocol](http://www.fixprotocol.org/). It would need to be able to cope with several clients (and then you get to learn Swing or some web techs) which requires concurrency.

If you are a beginner I suggest something simpler like a producer thread with a couple of consumer threads and you would get extra points if you can graphically show the process.

Answer (score 2):

A common learning project for concurrency and networking is to write a chat program.  It is similar to the FIX server suggestion but you just pass text around.

Answer (score 2):

When I read concurrent systems programming at the university, we built a video surveillance system - one master PC that fetched video data from one or more slave PC's with webcams. I remember that project since it really made you grok both efficient network programming, real-time issues and JNI :)

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend the book [Java Concurrency In Practice](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/) as a resource while you are working on whichever project you choose.